# Does getx enabled Flutter apps support the FirebaseAnalyticsObserver object when posting to Firebase Analytics?

Tags: flutter, google-analytics, flutter-getx

In a typical non-**getx** enabled Flutter app, I use **FirebaseAnalyticsObserver** to post to **Firebase Analytics** primarily in order to track the routes that are being visited in my Flutter app.

Can somebody tell me if **getx** supports **FirebaseAnalyticsObserver**? If so, does getx use it in the same way as in a non-getx Flutter app? (ie- Associate the **FirebaseAnalyticsObserver** instance with **MaterialApp:navigatorObservers** and if the app used named routes, that's all you have to do. If the app uses dynamic routes, slightly more code is needed when calling Navigator:push() to change routes.)

If getx does not support FirebaseAnalyticsObserver, what is the recommended method to track routes visited using Firebase Analytics? The only option that comes to mind is to manually post to Firebase Analytics in the constructor of the widget that abstracts the route which is kind of janky, after being used to FirebaseAnalyticsObserver.

As always, all help and suggestions is much appreciated.

/Jose

Answer (score 1):

Yes. GetX's `GetMaterialApp` also has `navigatorObservers` parameter.
You can use it in the same way as you do in `MaterialApp`.

Here's what the GetX document says:

> Note: this does not modify the MaterialApp of the Flutter, GetMaterialApp is not a modified MaterialApp, it is just a pre-configured Widget, which has the default MaterialApp as a child.

(https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx#counter-app-with-getx)